# Do I need to open port 8300 for consul servers in different DCs?

Tags: consul

I have created a Consul architecture that spans across different consul datacenters.
When I now open the UI on one of the consul servers, and switch via the little dropdown menu

[image]

to look at at a different datacenter the request times out. In the log I can see this error message:

```
2016/05/03 06:26:08 [ERR] http: Request GET /v1/internal/ui/nodes?dc=dc1-live&token=<hidden>, error: rpc error: failed to get conn: dial tcp xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8300: i/o timeout from=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53174
```

Does this mean I need to open port 8300 additionally to port 8302 between the servers of the different datacenters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having port 8300 being opended and that made the error messages go away. So I conclude that it is necessary.